# How to write a regular expression in c++

Tags: c++

I have this string `dummy_data:\m192.168.1.125\pApp` and I want to extract the IP address from the given string.

I have used the following regular Expression:

`\\\\m([\\d\\w\\.]+)\\\\?`

This returns `\m192.168.1.125`, but I want only `192.168.1.125`

Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: What are `\m` and `\p`? escaped character sequences or just literal backlash with character?

Comment: What has this got to do with c++? Are you using c++? Which regex library? There should be a regular-expression tag instead.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I'm guessing C++11 regex. Not sure if this is what the OP means, though.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about C++11 `<regex>`

Answer (score 0):

This one is simple:

```
[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?\.[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?\.[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?\.[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?
```

It only works for IPv4 addresses.

This one also worked for your string:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

I tested both on this [random page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html). I can not tell you how reliable they are.

Comment: i m using boost library and /m and /p is just a static data.